# Electron packaging with electron-packager - missing files in the build output

Tags: electron, electron-builder

here is my build command. current folder has additiona files like settings.config, readme.md these files are not included in the build output.

```
"build-win": "electron-packager . AppName --overwrite --out=dist --ignore='^/dist$' --prune --asar --platform=win32 --arch=all --version=0.36.0 --icon=img/favicon.ico"
```

This is the package.json

```
{
"name": "ElectronDesktopTest", 
"productName": "ElectronDesktopTest",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Electron Desktop Test",
"main": "main.js",
"electronVersion": "0.36.0",
"scripts": {
  "start": "electron main.js",
  "build-win": "electron-packager . ElectronDesktopTest --overwrite --out=dist --ignore='^/dist$' --prune --asar --platform=win32 --arch=all --version=0.36.0 --icon=img/favicon.ico"
  },
"author": "Jyo",
"devDependencies": {
    "electron-prebuilt": "^0.36.0",
    "electron-packager": "^5.2.0"
  },

"dependencies": {
   "electron-reload": "^0.2.0",
   "fs-extra": "^0.26.5",
   "gray-matter": "^2.0.2",
   "jade": "^1.11.0",
   "jquery": "^2.2.0",
   "lunr": "^0.6.0",
   "showdown": "^1.3.0",
   "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: do you minded o use the API of electron-packager instead command line?

Comment: What does your package.json look like? Do you have a `"files":` section?  
If so, try to remove it and see if that works.

Comment: Updated the main description with package.json Thanks

Answer (score -2):

If question tagged `electron-builder`, you can try to use [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) ;)

Comment: this doesn't help to the poster.